# git project vs repository, what's the fundamental difference?

Tags: git, repository, project, gitorious

I have two projects that currently use SVN and I'm migrating to git, I signed up to gitorious
and there's the option to create a new project or add a repository.
I'm just starting out with git so I don't know what the difference is, or rather what it means if I simply use to repositories under one project.
If i do that I'll end up with theirDomain.com/myname/repository1 and theirDomain.com/myname/repository2

If I choose to create two projects then I end up with 
theirDomain.com/project1
theirDomain.com/project2

Apart from the URL difference, will there be any implications in choosing one over the other?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 35, accepted):

That is a gitorious, not a git thing.  You can have multiple repositories per project.

For instance, if you have a client/server application.  You could have one project, and a repository for the client and a repo for the server inside it.

Answer (score 8):

With respect to the underlying git system itself and loose terms, a git repo is the .git dir. A git project is the parent dir containing the .git dir; the parent dir also serves as the 'working directory."

Three main sections of a Git project

1. Git directory, .git (also known as repository)
2. Working area/directory
3. Staging area (the index)

Answer (score 4):

Git has no such things as projects, only repositories. These projects are nothing more but a feature of Gitorious as it seems to me.

Answer (score 1):

It is just like if you use sourceforge, googlecode, redmine, trac or whatever: you have the repo where your actual code is, and then you have a broader project that includes your repo, but also has things like an issue tracker, maybe a wiki, etc....

It is all the other stuff that relates to your code, but isn't actually source code.