# How to add multiple project folders under ONE github repository?

Tags: git, android-studio, github, repository

I have a Homework repository on GitHub, where I am supposed to add my projects - written in Android Studio(on Windows). It adds the first project but the second one is unclickable with a different icon.
I moved my already existing folders into the repo folder, and did the following: add, commit and push origin. Nothing works. I tried with submodules but I get the error message, that the folder is not a valid git repo. 
I feel so lost in connection with github. I literally understand nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You must understand that projects and repositories are different things in git.
See here: [Project vs Repository in GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40509838/project-vs-repository-in-github).

If you have created a software project locally and want to add it to your profile as a distinguished repo, you must first convert it to a git repo.You can do it with `git init`

If you have created projects directly on github,see the answer i posted at the beginning

Answer (score 1):

First make sure the other projects do not have .git folder inside them. Otherwise they'll be treated as submodule. Then create a new folder and issue `git init` command (using git bash or whichever command line interface you have). Now that new folder is a git repo, move the project folders that do not contain `.git` folder in them into the new folder. Add everything using `git add *` and commit your changes.

Comment: That makes sense... one folder,one .git, and multiple projects within it ...