# Can we have multiple repositories inside a project in Github

Tags: github

I am developing an application with fronend and backend separated and communicated using REST API (say, backend is JAVA/.NET/NodeJS and frontend is React/Angular).

In BitBucket we can have a project and inside that project we can have multiple repository so that code base for backend and frontend can be in same container,

[image]

But in Github, if I am not wrong, concept of project is entirely different ([Project vs Repository in GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40509838/project-vs-repository-in-github)).
Is there any way to have this feature in Github. Because I have lot of projects which all have separate frontend and backend and it will be helpful if I can organize repositories for a single application in one place instead of keeping it with long list of other applications repositories.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: look at this explaining [HOW TO SETUP AND USE MULTIPLE GIT REPOSITORIES FOR ONE SINGLE PROJECT](https://bytescout.com/blog/setup-and-use-git-repositories-for-one-project.html). I hope it will helps...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a new GitHub feature called Lists that will help get you there. (it's actually still in beta)

It sounds like you're close to having this setup with what you're looking for.  At least you've started by using the Organization feature correctly.  Since GitHub uses the term Project for something other than what you want let's use Application instead.

In your case an Application has a front-end repository and a back-end repository.  In my case I have an Application with two client repositories (mobile app and web app) and an ecosystem of micro-services for the back-end.  So, about a dozen repositories for this one Application.

You can group these in three ways. (The second will answer your question)

First, if you're working with multiple clients/companies/groups you can associate a repository with an Organization.  This allows you to manage who has access and ownership of your repositories.

Second, you may have multiple Applications with multiple repositories each.  Your list of repositories will show them all.  If you want an easy way to group repositories together so you can filter to see just the related ones you use Lists.  It isn't the most obvious solution because you have to star a repository to be able to add it to a list.  Create a list from the stars page and name it after your Application, like "My Super Cool Auto-Dealership App."  Then add any of your repositories to that list.  The nice thing here is you can add any repository to the list even if you don't own it as long as it is starred.  Now you can view all the repositories that are used to build a single Application.

Third, you'll want to use Projects to organize the work that needs to be done for an Application.  So if you create a project and add your front-end and back-end repositories to it then you can see, organize, prioritize, and work issues for both repositories in one place.

So, we use the following GitHub features:

1. Organizations to manage who owns/accesses repositories
2. Lists to group/filter multiple repositories by Application
3. Projects to organize the work for multiple repositories

Comment: Another nice thing is that you can add a repo to multiple Lists.  So if you have a repo that is a common toolkit you import into multiple Applications you can add it to every List as well.

Answer (score 4):

The closest would be to combine:

- [GitHub Organization](https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.19/admin/user-management/creating-organizations) in order to declare in it all your repositories
- an [Organization-wide project board](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-your-work-on-github/about-project-boards) in order to manage all your issues and pull requests across those repositories within that organization.

Comment: The issue is I have multiple projects under an organization. But this solution will work for others. Thanks

Comment: @antajopaulson why "having multiple projects" is an issue with organization?

Comment: @Voc under one project I have multiple repositories (some times one single projects consists of 4 to 5 repositories). I know this is not a common situation.

Comment: @antajopaulson You coud then setup an organization just for that one project. It would still host your repositories.

Comment: I am working as service provider and I have multiple clients and each client  in my Github is an organization.