# On Github, what is the difference between a project managed in my account and the one on any repository?

Tags: github, merge, project-planning, github-projects

first I create a project in the account menu and linked to a repository:
[Screenshot of the menu of my github account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azgvH.png)

but when I go to my repository, I found nothing.[Screenshot of the project's tab on my repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjeu3.png)

How can I merge the account project and the repository project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading on the difference between [GitHub repositories and GitHub projects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43852027/6309), you have correctly associated at least one repository to your newly created project.

Your profile page ([`github.com/JulioMelchorPinto`](https://github.com/JulioMelchorPinto)) does show two projects.

If it should show "3", maybe you have associated to the new project a private repository.

Answer (score 0):

It is simply at a different level, there are account level projects and repository level projects.

Say I have projects that i want build for my portfolio, say todolist. In my account I would have a project for what it is that i need to do get that underway (hire staff, make the scaffolding for the project with create-react-app, buy a computer etc). Ok now that's done... time to start adding features to the repo that you have made... so make a project in the repo... maybe the todolist needs a list? Card for that, install a test suite? All the features i (might) put into the project for a repo... the account level is before you create a repo (at least in my world).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, in the "New" Projects, this is currently not possible. "New" Projects is currently beta, so we will have to see what happens. https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/52841